# It's Always There

Tags: riddle

A riddle I found somewhere and can't solve:

> It's always there, but you can't see it,
>   It's rare, but you can't catch it,
>   We used gold to make it.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  You might want to look around at some other posts before making your own, to see how things are done. I've moved the riddle out of the title and into the question body where it belongs - you should mention where this came from, and also verify that the entire riddle is present.

Comment: The snitch... ?

Comment: infinite possibilities

Answer (score 4):

It is

> Aura,

The hallow around a holy person/object or an angel, which is always there (Aurora Borialis and Aurora Australis as well can be linked here  !)

> Auras are rare and we cannot catch them

Usually it is / they are

> made of golden hues and the word itself is made of 'Au' - which is the chemical symbol for Gold

Comment: You barstool... You beat me to it...

Comment: @BrentHackers... language... please...

Answer (score 3):

Long shot...

> a halo

It's always there, but you can't see it,
It's rare, but you can't catch it,
We used gold to make it.

> a halo (supposedly), as attributed to a few persons of usually religious significance, is described as an unseen 'glow' often invisible but depicted as a golden circle or ring about a person's head.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone knows it is the

> Gold digger!

It's always there, but you can't see it,

> They're well hidden unless you shows your wealthiness.

It's rare, but you can't catch it,

> You cannot catch one - they approach if conditions are met.

We used gold to make it.

> Literally...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Oxygen

It's always there, but you can't see it

> it's in the air and it's invisible

it's rare

> Oxygen only makes up roughly 20% of the air, which some might call rare, although isn't oxygen the most common element in the Earth's crust?

you can't catch it

> It is of course a gas, so can't be caught

We used gold to make it

> I don't know who "we" is in this sentence, but plants 'make' oxygen through the use of sunlight, which has been likened to gold.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many interpretations as me and my friend came out with few others.

It's always there, but you can't see it,

It's rare, but you can't catch it,

> This will go with atmosphere. Always that means your lifetime or lifetime of this planet and we don't have that super eyes to see them. You can't catch it till you use specific apparatus for this task. For rare one, going with Hydrogen 0.53 ppm is its concentration. There can be other gases but why this one will answer for explanation of next line

We used gold to make it.

> Hydrogen is now required for fuel and lots of vehicle ( which are in testing) are working as public transport. Or space vehicles which are using them for long time. The process of getting hydrogen from water require gold/platinum as catalyst (expensive metals). This [link] (http://pubs.rsc.org/EN/content/articlelanding/2006/cp/b607837k/unauth#!divAbstract) would give better understanding. "We" here are humans or to be more specific chemists, scientist or traveller ( who uses those buses to commute to home or to space station).